# Calendar comparison

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am storing current date in SQLite DB as

```
created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I try to compare Calendar objects, its always shows objects as not equal.

Here is my code.

> Creating Calendar from Database string

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar calendarDB = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = "extracted only date (2014-03-03 for ex) from DB value ignoring time";
calendarDB.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
```

> Current Calendar instance

```
Calendar calendarCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();
```

> Comparison... I see not equal for all the instances.

```
if(calendarDB.equals(calendarCurrent))
    Log.i(TAG, "equal!!!");
else
    Log.i(TAG, "Not equal!!!");
```

I can see both Calendar instance values like day, month, year equal in Log.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Because you don't take in account the time... You should compare the dates only

Comment: The calendar value of this object is different

Comment: @ArtooDetoo - u mean to say, compare by year, month and day?

Comment: Yes. So you can compare the date independently of the time (you are actually creating a date which is set at midnight and compare with today at current time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Calendar.getInstance()` is not singleton. It every time creates a new instance of different implementations of `java.util.Calendar` based on `Locale`

Secondly, if you check equals method of `Calendar`, it checks lot more, than just the date

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
try {
    Calendar that = (Calendar)obj;
    return compareTo(getMillisOf(that)) == 0 &&
    lenient == that.lenient &&
    firstDayOfWeek == that.firstDayOfWeek &&
    minimalDaysInFirstWeek == that.minimalDaysInFirstWeek &&
    zone.equals(that.zone);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Note: GregorianCalendar.computeTime throws
    // IllegalArgumentException if the ERA value is invalid
    // even it's in lenient mode.
}
return false;
}
```

If you want to compare 2 dates then, you can do

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date one = new Date(); // one = calOne.getTime();
Date two = new Date(); //two = calTwo.getTime();
sdf.format(one).equals(sdf.format(two));
```

Comment: This works fine for equal but if I want to know whether particular date is before r after current date, how do I do it in current situation? In normal situations, I can use calendar's **before** and **after** methods

Comment: Even `Date` has `before()` and `after()` method right? :)

Answer (score 1):

That's happens because a `Calendar` equals method compare to next fields :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(object instanceof Calendar)) {
        return false;
    }
    Calendar cal = (Calendar) object;
    return getTimeInMillis() == cal.getTimeInMillis()
            && isLenient() == cal.isLenient()
            && getFirstDayOfWeek() == cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()
            && getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() == cal.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()
            && getTimeZone().equals(cal.getTimeZone());
}
```

So you need to check :

- millis
- isLenient
- first day of week
- minimal days in first week
- and time zone

As you can see equals method need a same `TimeZone` in comaprable object.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )        // Get today’s date in a particular time zone.
    .isEqual(                                        // Test for equality against a `LocalDate` object to be retrieved from database.
        myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )   // Retrieve a moment in UTC from the database, an `Instant` object.
            .atZone( ZoneId( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Produce a `ZonedDateTime` to represent the same moment in time but with the wall-clock time of a particular region’s time zone.
            .toLocalDate()                           // Extract a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you may directly exchange java.time objects with your database. No need for the troublesome `Calendar` class, no need for mere strings.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply the `ZoneId` to your `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you care about only the date portion, and not the time-of-day, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare to the current date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
Boolean isSameDateAsToday = ld.isEqual( today ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).